# Duplicating node if

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, xmlnode

I can't quite wrap my brains around this - I only do XSLT seldomly. On a condition I need to duplicate a node. I have looked at "template" and "copy", but don't know how to make them work together.

The XML I have

```
<data>
  <product>
    <productnumber>655.43</productnumber>
    <parentproduct></parentproduct>
  </product>
  <product>
    <productnumber>655.38</productnumber>
    <parentproduct>655.43</parentproduct>
  </product>
</data>
```

The XML I want

```
<data>
  <product>
    <productnumber>655</productnumber>
    <parentproduct></parentproduct>
  </product>
  <product>
    <productnumber>655.43</productnumber>
    <parentproduct>655</parentproduct>
  </product>
  <product>
    <productnumber>655.38</productnumber>
    <parentproduct>655</parentproduct>
  </product>
<data>
```

So, if parentproduct is empty, the product node should be duplicated.

The xsl I'm messing with looks like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="column"/>
<xsl:template match="/data/product">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl: apply-templates select="/data/product"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

So I need some "stuff" in the select statement on the apply-templates...but can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Regards /Snedker

Comment: "*So, if parentproduct is empty, the product node should be duplicated.*" That's not what your example shows - please clarify.

Comment: 655.43 indicates 655 being main product (ProductID), and 43 a variant (VariantID). Table-wise there must be one row with ProductID and no VariantID (master). Next, all variant rows have ProductID+VariantID.

My trouble is that the master (with no parentproduct) also acts as a variant (hence the content in product).

The "XML I want" shows a master product + two variants.

Hope this clarifies. And thanks for your efforts!

BR /Morten

Comment: I am afraid I am still not fully with you. The input XML shows that 655.43 is the parent product of 655.38. This information is lost in the transformation. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The problem is that the 655.43 holds BOTH the information of being a parent (empty <parentproduct>) AND the information of a variant (.43). I need to split this information so that the parent product has NO variant information. And so that all variants point to a parent with NO variant information (in this case just: <productnumber>655</productnumber>). And all variants should then have <parentproduct>655</parentproduct>

Comment: Do I understand correctly then that the solution should simply ignore all `parentproduct` tags - empty or not - and group the `productnumber` "variants" under a common parent, given by the integer part of the number?

Comment: P.S. Please indicate whether using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Yes, that is understood correctly.
As for the version that'd be 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling I am still missing something here, but try the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="product-by-parent" match="productnumber" use="substring-before(., '.')" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
        <!-- for each unique integer part of productnumber -->
        <xsl:for-each select="data/product/productnumber[count(. | key('product-by-parent', substring-before(., '.'))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="parent" select=" substring-before(., '.')" />
            <product>
                <productnumber><xsl:value-of select="$parent"/></productnumber>
                <parentproduct/>
            </product>
            <!-- for each productnumber starting with the current integer -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('product-by-parent',  $parent)">
                <product>
                    <productnumber><xsl:value-of select="."/></productnumber>
                    <parentproduct><xsl:value-of select="$parent"/></parentproduct>
                </product>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

IMHO, your output schema could be improved by wrapping the child products inside a common parent element.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you'd better use `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`, which reproduces an exact full-depth copy of the current node.

Comment: The information I find suggests that copy-of isn't good for a following manipulation of the attributes. But I'm a noob, so I could be wrong. Thx for you input!

BR